# Sort a ComboBox in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, combobox

I am trying to sort a ComboBox without success so far.
I am using the classic code below found on internet:

```
 Sub SortComboBox(ByRef oCB As ComboBox)
    Dim vItems As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim vTemp As Variant
    ' Put the items in a array
    vItems = oCB.List
    ' Sort the array
    For i = LBound(vItems, 1) To UBound(vItems, 1) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(vItems, 1)
            If vItems(i, 0) > vItems(j, 0) Then
                vTemp = vItems(i, 0)
                vItems(i, 0) = vItems(j, 0)
                vItems(j, 0) = vTemp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ' Clear the ComboBox
    oCB.Clear
    ' Add the sorted array back to the ComboBox
    For i = LBound(vItems, 1) To UBound(vItems, 1)
        oCB.AddItem vItems(i, 0)
    Next i
End Sub
```

I am calling this Sub with this line:

```
SortComboBox (Sheet1.cboSolvent)
```

The ComboBox 'cboSolvent' is on the Worksheet1 and is already filled from the worksheet2. I am calling the Sub 'SortComboBox' when the ComboBox 'cboSolvent' is already full but not sorted.

I get the following error: 'object required', but I don't understand, because for me, cboSolvent is an object (a ComboBox object).
Moreover, Sheet1.cboSolvent is highlighted with the message: Sheet1.cboSolvent = "Data". Another thing unclear for me as it should be Sheet1.cboSolvent.Text = "Data".

Any help will be appreciated to sort this issue of course, but also to understand the things I don't understand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call it as (without brackets)

```
SortComboBox Sheet1.cboSolvent
```

If you need to call the sub with brakets then use CALL keyword.

```
Call SortComboBox(Sheet1.cbsolvent)
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew these 2 notations, but I guess I create a new one which does not exist. Sorry to be so dumb! Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked out , No need to be sorry that's how you learn !